# Marijuana Smell Blocking During Local Travel

Tags: smell, container

I live in a place where recreational marijuana use is 100% legal and I'm looking for the best hacks to conceal the smell of marijuana while driving for an amount of half an ounce or less.

I'm fine with answers that someone has that's just amazingly effective for any amount of half an ounce or less. So this means hacks for 1 gram up to 16 grams and everything in between. I need the answers to be extremely effective and I will put them to the test.

I would prefer to not have to rely on any chemical compounds and focus on more containment of the smell via a wrapping method, some sort of container and the alike. If it doesn't involve spraying chemicals, I'm listening.

**Reason**

I need to pick up some relatives in my state but the trip is a couple hours each way and they will be traveling back with me and I need to block the smell for my elderly grandmother due to allergies but I must take what is needed and a little extra so not taking any is not an answer.

**Potency**

Assume the potency and smell of this type of marijuana is the strongest and smelliest stuff out there at the moment when you answer.

Comment: <rant> You appear to value the senses of your elderly grandmother less than your own. How do you intend to test your theory; by exposing your relative with an allergy when you arrive and the vehicle and yourself is contaminated? Allergies are not a condition of choice. The allergy may be mild or profound - you have no way to evaluate the efficacy of ANY method offered as you don't have the necessary sensitivity to the condition. If you do care, do take care. </rant> I didn't DV you, BTW.

Comment: @Stan YOU appear to be making a value judgement without really knowing much about what you're talking about.  There are few known cases relating to allergic rhinitis from marijuana pollen -none by smell alone. There are cases of serious allergies (anaphylaxis) with ingestion, while exceedingly rare, but nobody is going to suffer or die if they were inadvertently exposed to the smell of some pot! This person is merely assuring that there are no issues with smell sensitivity. If you have an agenda, it is better served elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure marijuana use is legal while driving?

Comment: Transportation of it ( not while smoking it) is perfectly legal within a state  where it's legal. Interstate travel is generally illegal, however (aside from travel to another state, that's adjacent, and where the substrate is also legalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy! Put it in a thoroughly cleaned jar. If you have a full 1/2 (14grams), you should be able to put this in the smallest sized mason jar. This is also great for general storage of legal /medical marijuana, as it is airtight; completely "smell proof"; and will not allow your flowers to dry out - in fact it will continue the curing process. If you don't want to buy mason jars, any glass food jar or any airtight container that is glass will work. Just make sure that if you're using something that once contained food, that after cleaning the jar you remove any rubber on the interior of the cap ( some have this some don't); the rubber will retain the food smell despite washing. For smaller amounts, empty  prescription medicine bottles with the label removed work excellent for this purpose.

Comment: Excellent, will test with mason job and old prescription pill bottle. You will get +1 from me once I get 15 rep points.

Comment: @SlickNutz cool. Zero smell; all good!

Comment: Both methods were effective just as you suggested. I will personally go with the pill bottle for the amount carried during travel. I got some slight seepage from the method in the other answer but your suggestions seems to keep it locked in air tight for many many hours with absolutely no smell when the container are in a small car that stayed parked with sun beaming down on it so I accept your answer. Thank you Gracey!!

Comment: Awesome! Happy I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

Drug dealers have been putting pot into coffee beans for a while and you could do the same. Nest the double bagged pot inside a larger bag of black-roasted coffee beans.

After a couple of hours, it will begin to leak. For more insulation, put the whole package into a thermos jug. It will be good for a while longer.

These will mask an odour NOT prevent the allergen from making your outwardly grateful passengers, inwardly uncomfortable victims of exposure.

What do you intend to do about your car interior, clothes, and breath in the automobile after you smoke enroute?

Comment: I will put this to the test soon. Put in a thermos and then into coffee beans and see how long before the smell lingers. I'm more worried about the smell than the allergen and I don't smoke enroute while driving. I used a different solution for the personal clothing worn at the time of smoking outside and away from the vehicle. I probably should take the Allergy comment out of my question. You get +1 as soon as I get 15 points I think regardless and I will report back my results for your answer\methods. Feel free to add more answers for other methods, I need to compare tests, I'm upvoting all.

Comment: @SlickNutz You have things reversed. Re-read what's inside of what.

Comment: I see thanks I'm going to test this soon. I'm hoping for more answer and more upvotes so I can upvote the answers I get on this post.